# android compatibility API alternatives to PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, compatibility, fragment, preference

I want to display a main menu on the left and a settings page on the right of the screen. I want to use the Android compatibility API and fragments.

I also want to make use of the Android preferences features and add the preferences from .xml file, and don't want to use workarounds (like personally customized list views, linear layouts, etc). What options do I have, considering that PreferenceFragment is not included in the compatibility API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ActionBarSherlock's [PreferenceActivity](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) plugin.

[Here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos) is the sample source code.

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos